# How to pass a function row by row in R and export results in a data frame

Tags: r, function

I'm quite new in R.
I have a function that uses 3 data frames to generate reports (basically `do.reports` does a couple does some calculation among the tables and merged them.

```
create_report = do_reports(df1, df2, df3)

ID = c("ID1", "ID2", "ID3")
size = c(2, 5, 4)
p = c(0.05, 0.1, 0.3)
var = c(0.3, 0.5, 1.2)
location = c("blood", "tissue", "blood")

df1 = data.frame(ID  = ID , size= size, p = p)
df2 = data.frame(ID  = ID , var = var)
df3 = data.frame(ID  = ID , location = location)
```

The output of this consists in 2 different objects ( `create_report[1]`, `create_report[2]`)

```
#expected create_report[1]

create_report[1] = data.frame(ID  = ID , location = location, size = size , p=p)

 #expected create_report[2]

create_report[2] = data.frame(location = location, size = size , p=p, var=var)
```

However, I would like to use `do_reports` row by row in df2 (something like `create_report = do_reports(df1, df2[1,], df3)`, save the results independently and once finishes, merge all of them in a table.
What I've tried so far is:

```
for (i in seq_len(nrow(df2) {
  create_report = do_reports(df1, df2, df3)
}
```

I know that using a loop over it could be very tedious, so I was wondering if someone in here could help me with this.

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to SO, Lila McPhee! Please make this question *reproducible*. This includes sample code you've attempted (including listing non-base R packages, and any errors/warnings received), sample *unambiguous* data (e.g., `data.frame(x=...,y=...)` or the output from `dput(head(x))`), and intended output given that input. Refs: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269, [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.

Comment: thank you for the comment, is now clearer?

Answer (score 0):

```r
library(tidyverse)
ID <- c("ID1", "ID2", "ID3")
size <- c(2, 5, 4)
p <- c(0.05, 0.1, 0.3)
var <- c(0.3, 0.5, 1.2)
location <- c("blood", "tissue", "blood")

df1 <- data.frame(ID = ID, size = size, p = p)
df2 <- data.frame(ID = ID, var = var)
df3 <- data.frame(ID = ID, location = location)


do_report <- function(ID, size, p, var, location) {
  # create some result
  result <- "test"
  
  write_rds(result, file = tempfile())
}

list(df1, df2, df3) %>%
  reduce(full_join) %>%
  mutate(result = list(ID, size, p, var, location) %>% pmap(do_report))
```

Comment: I think you have misunderstood my question. What I want to do is to pass the function do_reports row by row in df2 (something like create_report = do_reports(df1, df2[1,], df3), save the results independently and once finishes, merge all of them in a table. I can do it with a loop but is not very efficient.

Comment: You have not provided functions `do.reports` or `do_report` as mentioned in the question. Does saving means writing the result to files?

Comment: yes, I mean writing the result for each row (or save them independently) and combined them in a df at the end

Comment: `list(df1, df2, df3) %>% lapply(do_report)` can be used instead of a for loop to apply teh function `do_report` on every element of the list

Comment: but I want to pass it row by row as I saw in the `for`  loop

Comment: I revised my answer, This produced one file per ID. Input arguments of the reporting func are still missing.

Comment: According to the question, the for loop will create three identical files.